# How do I iterate through a list of dictionaries to make sure the I don't add the same name?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[{"History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"], "Calculus": [billy]}]
```

I want to traverse the name of the classes so when I add the next class, I make sure that class isn't in the list. And then I want to traverse that class to make sure there isn't a student with the same name added twice.

I made this code:

```
with open('students.json') as j:
       data = json.load(j)
for classRoom in data:
       print "entered here4"
       #classCheck = data[classRoom]
       #this checks if the classroom is already in the dictionary of lists
       if(className == classRoom):
          print "entered here5"        
          for student in data[classRoom]:
                if(studentName == student):
                print "student already in this classroom"
                       sys.exit()
          data[classRoom].append(studentName)
          with open ('students.json', 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(data,outfile)
           print "student added to class"
           sys.exit()
```

`if(className == classRoom):` This if statement is skipped when I run the code. And if I change `classCheck==data[classRoom]` I get an error "list indices must be integers, not dict. What can I change in the for loop so it checks if the classroom name exists or not?

Comment: The word "class" is typically a reserved word in object-oriented programming languages, so use another variable name such as "classname" or "myclass" or "c".

Comment: @jarmod Oh sorry! Didn’t realize. I changed the variable names. Hope it clears things up

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you should be doing:
assuming `data = [{"History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"], "Calculus": [billy]}]`

```
for classRoom, studentList in data[0].items(): #this grabs both keys and values in the dictionary, then
    if className in classRoom:
        #do something ..
    for i in studentList: #since values are list
        if studentName in i:# this grabs each values list and check if student exist there
            #do somthing ...
```

Comment: Thanks that helped with finding the class room and names but when I want to add a name, I get an error for the append line saying "list indices must be integers, not unicode". How can I change the append name so it adds to that classRoom?
Edit: figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, "class" is a reserved keyword, but otherwise, just have two dictionaries ("students" and "classes") and check add the student or class after checking it is not already there.

Comment: Yea sorry, I changed it. I'm still new python didn't realize. Instead of having two dictionaries, is there a way to change my for loop so it can check the keys? So it can then go into the if statement to see if it adds the name or not.

Answer (score 0):

You json is a list of dictionary. When you iterate over the list,

```
for classRoom in data:
    # classRoom is the whole dictionary - {"History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"], "Calculus": ["billy"]}
```

Change the JSON to a dictionary like this-

```
{"History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"], "Calculus": ["billy"]}
```

Now,

```
for classRoom in data:
    # classRoom is a key-value pair - "History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"] for the first iteration
```